# Help on Python Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, python, python3

I installed bpython3 from the store.
Everything seems to work fine and I just don't know how can I run the code I writed. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: All `bpython` can do seems to be written in `man bpython`. Not *that* much it seems. I'd recommend using something like `Idle3`.

Answer (score 0):

bpython is a fancy interface to the Python interpreter. I can't get a Python development environment like Spyder to install in my Python virtual environment, but bpython is installed there and it runs OK.

1. bpython3 is run from the terminal. Open the terminal and type `bpython3` to start bpython3.
2. Type a program one line at a time and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to a new line. Every time you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the Python3 interpreter reads and executes the current line interactively. As you can see from the screenshot, bpython3 has an in-line syntax highlighting feature.
3. You can save the bpython3 session at any time using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. You will be prompted to type a name for the saved file. The session will be saved by default to your Home directory.
4. Type `exit()` after the Python interpreter prompt or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to exit bpython3.

   [image]